# Why would $env:username and [environment]::username return different users?

Tags: powershell

What is the difference between PowerShell's `$env:username` and `[environment]::username` and **why would they potentially return different users**?  (I understand there are other ways to get the current user as well)

*Some background:*

I have an Azure Pipeline that runs a PowerShell script on a release target.  The pipeline agent is configured to run under a specific service account.  Part of that PowerShell script uses `$env:username` to assign permissions.  However, permissions are assigned to the local admin account instead.  If I change the script to use `[environment]::username` the correct service account user is given permissions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$env:USERNAME`, while *predefined* to reflect the current user's username, is a *read-write* environment variable, just like any other.

Even though it's obviously inadvisable to do so, a statement such as `$env:USERNAME = 'foo'` changes the value of environment variable `USERNAME` for the current process as well as its child processes.

This means that **if environment variable `USERNAME` was modified earlier in the same session or in PowerShell's *parent* process, possibly via an explicitly specified startup environment, it no longer reflects the true username**.

While I don't know why the `USERNAME` environment variable would differ from the real account in the case of Azure Pipelines, an example of - inadvertently - setting the wrong value is PowerShell's `Start-Process` cmdlet when given the `-UseNewEnvironment` switch: due to a bug as of PowerShell Core 7.0.0-preview.5 / Windows PowerShell v5.1, `$env:USERNAME` unexpectedly always reflects `SYSTEM`, irrespective of the actual user account - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4671).

By contrast, [`[Environment]::UserName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.username#System_Environment_UserName) uses a different method for obtaining the current user's username, which does not rely on the value of `$env:USERNAME` and always reflects the true username<sup>[1]</sup>.

In short: **Only `[Environment]::UserName` reliably reflects the current user account's username.**

---

<sup>[1] From the [linked docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.username?view=netcore-3.0#System_Environment_UserName): "On Windows the `UserName` property wraps a call to the Windows [`GetUserName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms724432.aspx) function. The domain account credentials for a user are formatted as the user's domain name, the `\` character, and user name. Use the `UserDomainName` property to obtain the user's domain name and the `UserName` property to obtain the user name.

On Unix platforms the `UserName` property wraps a call to the `getpwuid_r` function.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation.  For those interested, since writing the question I have confirmed in the pipeline logs (on the deployment group job initialization step) that a `username` environment variable is getting set to the local admin account.

Answer (score 1):

$env: is looking at your environmental variables. The variable that you're looking at- username- happens to be set to the local username by default. But it doesn't have to be.

[Environment] is a call to the [System.Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment?view=netframework-4.8) class in .NET Framework. This class has a property called UserName that contains the username that is logged into the computer.

Similiar names, but very different things. You could get the path statement by $env:Path, for example, or call [Environment]::Version to get the version of .NET Framework.

Note in this example I deliberately messed with the local environmental variable prior to launching PowerShell to give the wrong username.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>echo %username%
mspow

C:\WINDOWS\system32>set username=bob

C:\WINDOWS\system32>echo %username%
bob

C:\WINDOWS\system32>powershell
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> echo $env:username
bob
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> [Environment]::Username
mspow
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> echo $env:ProgramFiles
C:\Program Files
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> echo $env:path
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\mspow\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> [Environment]::Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
4      0      30319  42000
```

You can see all of the available environment variables by using

```
Get-Item -Path Env:
```

The only way I know of to see all of the Methods and Properties for [Environment] is the link to the MSDN site. Get-Member doesn't work on it.

Comment: `$env:USERNAME` and `[Environment]::UserName` are _technically_ distinct things, but _conceptually_ they are meant to contain the same information - though indeed you can only falsify the former, not the latter. `[Environment]` is a _static_ class; if you want to see its members, use `[Environment] | Get-Member -Static`. As an aside: If you want to inspect a type's _instance_ members, there is currently no way to do that by way of the type itself - you need an instance, which may be nontrivial to construct - see [this GitHub suggestion](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6382).